# How to use libjass

Tags: javascript, lib

I'am using this example, but don't work. What should I do ??

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" muted controls style="width: 720px; height: auto">
<source src="./vjs/Ansatsu_Kyoushitsu_2_01_Koisuru-PA-Anbient.mkv" type="video/mkv">
<link href="libjass.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="libjass.js"></script>
<script>
    var assLoadedPromise = libjass.ASS.fromUrl(".vjs/en.ass");
    var video = document.querySelector("#video");
    assLoadedPromise.then(function (ass) {
        var renderer = new libjass.renderers.DefaultRenderer(video, ass);
    });
</script>
</video>
```

Return error `playersub:218 Uncaught ReferenceError: libjass is not defined
    at playersub:218`

Comment: Has "libjass.js" been properly loaded by the browser? What is the deployed file hierarchy?

Comment: `libjass.js`is in the same directory as `playersub.js`

Comment: Please update the question itself on requests for improvements. Can you show exactly how you are providing and running your web application? Is there any other error message?

Comment: This is only error message, libjass.jsis in the exactly same directory as playersub.js, is it.

Comment: Whether the script is in the same directory as another script is not relevant. In fact, we don't see a "playersub.js" in your questing. You should make sure that you provide us a [MCVE].